# @fontface on blackberry os 7

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to load a font that works fine everywhere but not on blackberry OS 7

```
@font-face {font-family: 'CCDoohickeyOpen';src: url('webfonts/244FAC_0_0.eot');
src:     url('webfonts/244FAC_0_0.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/244FAC_0_0.woff') f
ormat('woff'),url('webfonts/244FAC_0_0.ttf')
format('truetype'),url('webfonts/244fac_0_0-webfont.svg#CCDoohickeyOpen') 
format('svg');}
```

the page is at http://lisp.li what am I doing wrong? Ironically other web fonts from other sites seems to work fine on bb 7. thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### BB supports only SVG Files

The Blackberry browser on BB OS5, 6 and 7 only supports SVG font files (you can use fontsquirrel to convert from other formats).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CCDoohickeyOpen';
    src: url('webfonts/244fac_0_0-webfont.svg#CCDoohickeyOpen') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: The code in the question has an SVG version of the font, too. And it seems to be OK as such; I tested with code that refers to that SVG version only, and it works on Chrome.

Comment: the problem was that font squirrel does not rename the svg so, to other people, be sure to check the svg first line that has to match the font family name :) this is solved and works now thanks!!

Comment: To further clarify this, the `id` of the `font` element in the SVG file (can be named whatever) needs to match the `font-family` attribute in the `@font-face`, as well as referenced in the `src` attribute as above (i.e. appended with `#CCDoohickeyOpen`).