# fontawesome icons not displaying in Android app

Tags: android, css, cordova, fonts

We're coding an Android app using fontawesome icons. Our app works fine with fontawesome icons on iOS but nothing for Android. I tried all sorts of online fixes and none of them worked, and I really don't feel like creating a few hundred different PNG's for each screen resolution.

What do I do? I can't do this: [How to use icons and symbols from "Font Awesome" on Native Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application/15762875#15762875)

The way we're defining it (fontawesome.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

With all of our fonts in fonts/fontawesome.

Not a single clue on how to get this working on Android..

Comment: Are your fonts folder and fontawesome.css file in the same directory? If so try putting `./` before `fonts` in your URL.

Comment: They are not in the same folder, they work on iOS so the path is correct.

Comment: Have you tried the below solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028602/font-awesome-icons-are-not-working-in-some-browsers

Comment: also check this article: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-use-icon-fonts-in-android.html

Comment: Solved it by changing an android specific stylesheet that was overriding a link to my font file. That's all, hahaha.

Comment: @eveo, best to write that as the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove the version paramter `?v=3.2.1`

`src: url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot');`

some old webkit can't recognize the url with paramaters